# Solutions to a quadratic given 1 solution in form a+bi

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics

I was just really confused as to how I only ended up with 1 of 2 answers for the following question.

Given that $-2+bi$ is a solution of $x^2+ax+(3+a) $ find constants $a$ and $b$ given that they are real.

As soon as I saw that $-2+bi$ was a solution, I immediately jumped to $ -2-bi$  must also be a solution, by the fundamental theorem of algebra. By doing the sum and product of the solution a quadratic could be obtained

Sum $ (-2+bi)+(-2-bi)=-4$

Product $(-2-bi)(-2+bi)=(-2)^2-(-bi)^2=4+b^2$

Thus the quadratic $x^2+4x+(4+b^2)$ is obtained

Equation both sides of the equation

$\\x^2+4x+(4+b^2)=x^2+ax+(3+a)$

$a=4$

Therefore$ b={\sqrt 3}$   or $ b={-\sqrt 3}$

However, the solutions seem to suggest that an extra solution can be
$ b={0}, a=7$

Did I eliminate a solution by doing the sum and product of the solutions to find the quadratic? Or does it have to do with my working process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a solution when you assumed that $-2-bi$ was the other root. If $b \neq 0$, then yes, that must be the other root. But if $b = 0$, the other root can be whatever other real number it needs to be. (Also, the fundamental theorem of algebra does not say that non-real roots come in complex conjugate pairs.)

Comment: So for any solution in the form *−2+bi*, the case for *b=0* must be made?

Comment: @R.Su Yes. If one of the roots is $-2$, rather than, say, $-2+i$, then you don't immediately know what the other root is.

Comment: Ah, I see. I went by the line from the fundamental theorem of algebra
If  *p+qi* (*q≠0*) is a zero of a real polynomial then its complex conjugate *p-qi* is also a zero

Comment: The FTA *does* imply non-real roots come in conjugate pairs, if the polynomial's coefficients are real, as in this case. It takes a little effort to prove that *from* the FTA, though.

Comment: @J.G. Right, I see. I feel like I need to look through this more carefully next time. Thank you! :)

Comment: @J.G. It's a lot easier to just say "If $P(z) = 0$ for some real polynomial $P$ and complex $z$, then $P(\bar z) = \overline{P(z)} = 0$". This only uses fundamental algebraic properties of conjugation. No need to assume that roots exist in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

A brute force approach is to substitute $x=-2+bi$ into $x^2+ax+(3+a)$. Then
\begin{align}
x^2+ax+(3+a)
&= (-2+bi)^2+a(-2+bi)+(3+a) \\ 
&=(7-a-b^2)+b(a-4)i \\
\end{align}
where I have organized the last expression into real and imaginary parts (since $a,b$ are assumed real). If this last expression is to vanish as desired, then both real and imaginary parts are zero. From the latter, we deduce that $b=0$ or $a=4$. If $b=0$, then the condition $7-a-b^2=0$ yields $a=7$. If $a=4$, then this same condition implies $b^2=7-a=3$ and therefore $b=\pm \sqrt{3}$. This gives all three solutions.

Comment: Another way of thinking about it, however, I wonder which method is more concise? 
i.e. proving for each case of *b* or directly subbing in.

Comment: @R.Su Perhaps the most concise is this: If $b=0$, then $x=-2$ is a root of $x^2+ax+3+a$ when $4-2a+3+a=0\implies a=7$. If not, then the polynomial must factorize as $(x+2-bi)(x+2+bi)=(x+2)^2+b^2=x^2+4x+(4+b^2)$ and therefore $a=4,b^2=3$.

Answer (score 2):

Let the second root be $c-ib$ (because $2+ib+c-ib=a$ must be real). Then

$$(x+2-ib)(x-c+ib)=x^2+(2-c)x-2c+b^2+i(bc+2b)=x^2+ax+a+3.$$

For the imaginary term to vanish, $$b=0\lor c=-2$$

gives us the three solutions

$$a=7,b=0,c=-5$$ and $$a=4,b=\pm\sqrt3,c=-2.$$

Comment: Would it be wise to introduce more variables than needed? I feel like for some people this may introduce more rooms to make mistakes. 
However, this is also a good answer. Thanks!

Comment: @R.Su: the goal of this answer is to show that three solutions exist and this appears in the discussion via the equation $bc-2b=0$. The variable $c$ is essential. Your resolution was incomplete for the very reason that you decided $c=2$ prematurely.

Comment: Hmm. I feel like I should go back and revisit polynomials. Thanks for the excellent answer! :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I hv a doubt: for non zero b, your root is coming out to be $ 2 - i b$ Not a CC pair to first one ? should have been $ - 2 - i b$ ?

Comment: @math: shame on me, I made sign errors. Hopefully fixed now.